# AMD GPU fluctuates utilization and clock speed on restart

Tags: pc, civilization-6, graphics-card

I'm trying to play Civ6 at bare minimum settings and my hardware reaches recommended requirements, but sometimes when I boot the game it runs at 5fps with very little GPU utilization and ~ 200MHz clock speed.

My current fix is to reboot my machine and load in again, which sometimes does fix the problem and I get ~60fps with a GPU clock speed ~1000MHz.

Any tips on how to get more consistent performance?

Specs:
HP Elitebook 840G5 with built-in AMD Radeon RX 540 updated to latest driver version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD has a feature called "Cool and Quiet" which a lot of people have been having issues with lately.

- Make sure you have the latest chipset drivers installed.
- According to [this post by an AMD employee](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/cbls9g/the_final_word_on_idle_voltages_for_3rd_gen_ryzen/), monitoring tools such as CPU-Z can screw up the Cool and Quiet feature. They recommend [AMD Ryzen Master Utility](https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/ryzen-master)
- If all else fails, you can disable the feature in the BIOS.  You could also try setting "Power Plan" to "High Performance" in Windows *(Control Panel --> Power Options --> Advanced)*. Note that both of these will reduce battery times.